# помогите с задачей с++ работа с файлами

Tags: c++, ооп, работа-с-текстом

> Скопировать содержимое файла indata.dat в файл outdata.dat и подсчитать  и вывести на экран количество строк в файле.

вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// () для записи использует функцию put()
bool countlines(const char* readFile, const char* writeFile)
{
    int count = 0;
    ifstream rf(readFile, ios::in | ios::binary);

    // проверка, открыт ли файл
    if (!rf.is_open())
        return false;

    ofstream wf(writeFile, ios::out | ios::binary);

    // проверка, открыт ли файл
    if (!wf.is_open())
    {
        rf.close(); // закрыть ранее открытый файл rf
        return false;
    }

    char sym;

    // цикл посимвольного чтения
    while (rf)
    {
        rf.get(sym); // считать из rf => sym
        if (rf) wf.put(sym); // записать sym => wf
        
    }
    cout << count ;//кол-во строк
    rf.close(); // закрыть оба файла
    wf.close();
}
void main()
    {
        countlines("indata.dat", "outdata.dat");
    }
```

Comment: Не силён в с++, но в файл вы пишете с условием `if (rf) wf.put(sym);`, а счётчик увеличиваете без условия.

Comment: Так кол-во строк или все же слов?

Comment: Во-первых, неясно, а зачем они открываются как бинарные? во-вторых, непонятно, что за символ вы считываете предварительно, а потом слово? Что вы хотите этим добиться? И вообще - что у вас записано в файле? (это все не считая вопроса, заданного @Maggot). И еще - при чем тут метка `c#` или `c`? Или вам нужен любой язык? И, кстати, число строк - это по сути число `\n`, если файл заканчивается `\n`, или на одну больше, если нет (конечно, пустая строка - это тоже строка :))

Comment: В си нет ООП...

Comment: `if (rf) wf.put(sym);` **`else break;`**

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

bool countline(const char* readFile, const char* writeFile)
{
    int count = 0;
    char* str = new char[1024];
    ifstream rf(readFile, ios::in);

    if (!rf.is_open())
        return false;

    ofstream wf(writeFile, ios::out);

    if (!wf.is_open())
    {
        rf.close();
        return false;
    }

    char sym;

    while (!rf.eof())
    {
        rf.get(sym);
        if (rf) wf.put(sym);
        rf.getline(str, 1024, '\n');
        count++;
    }
    cout << count;
    rf.close();
    wf.close();
}
void main()
{
    countline("indata.dat", "outdata.dat");
}
```